# x-axis offset and missing x-axis data points in qplot histogram (R)

Tags: r, ggplot2, formatting

In my histogram, it looks like the bars are floating. I want to remove the offset of the x-axis. Also, I want -3 and 3 displayed as points on the x-axis.

[image: simple histogram]

My code:

```
qplot(cognitivecat, geom="histogram", binwidth = 0.5, xlab = 'CSS Scores', 
ylab = 'Number of Observations') + theme_bw() + theme(
plot.background = element_blank()
,panel.grid.major = element_blank()
,panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
,panel.border = element_blank()
) + theme(axis.line.x = element_line(color="black", size = 0.25),
      axis.line.y = element_line(color="black", size = 0.25))
```

Comment: look at the `expand` argument to` scale_y_continuous`. Also look at the `breaks` argument in the x equivalent.

Comment: adding `scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(-3,-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3)) + scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))` helped. Thanks! Found the explanation here: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_continuous.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> adding `+ scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(-3,-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3)) + scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0))` helped. Thanks Richard! Found the explanation here: docs.ggplot2.org/current/scale_continuous.html